# How exactly Android creates external storage folder?

Tags: android

We know `getExternalCacheDir()` method will return `File` Object and automatic create folder `"/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.domain.packagename/cache"`
But how exactly Android does this?
When I write C code to create folder `"/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.domain.packagename"`, it failed. I have to call `getExternalCacheDir()` in Java code first.
I just want to know is there any way to create external storage folder purely in ndk.

Comment: On Android 11+ devices you have no acces to that `data` directory. No write access. No read access. If you call that function the OS will create an app specific directory to which your app has full access.

Comment: @blackapps Yes but is there any C interface we can call to create specific directory. I mean it works on kotlin and java. And I want to know why `getExternalCacheDir()` can create folder in `data` directory